# How  to get upper case sequences from string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

In **PHP**, how do I get only upper case sequences from the string?

For example, how can I get from:

```
abcDEF GHi jklm
```

only:

```
DEF GH
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find matches:

```
preg_match('/[A-Z]+/', $input, $matches);
```

To remove all *"wrong"* stuff:

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^A-Z ]/', '', $input);
```

Comment: `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g'`

Answer (score 4):

use this regular expression `[A-Z]+`

Comment: Looks like he wants the whitespace too. and you might want to add a php sample

Comment: Its correct but you are using reverse case :D it should be `[a-z]+` should be `preg_replace('/[a-z]+/', '', 'abcDEF GHi jklm')` Anyway its perfect!

Comment: @4lvin - 4lvin: You are wrong, or your question is wrong. How you want to deal with stuff like `@#$%^&*()1234567890~;'.,<>/?{}\|][-_=+` ..?

Answer (score 1):

A string of upper case letters can be matched with `[A-Z]+`

However, if you specifically want words that are only upper case, then you need to add a word boundary marker to each end of the expression. This is `\b`.

So your expression would look like this:

```
/\b[A-Z]+\b/
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Ωmega - hm, fair enough; I read the title more carefully than the question ;)

Comment: Sometimes same happen to me :) (S)he also wants to keep whitespaces, I believe... You still can edit your question with some lesson about `\b` as OP probably might be interested to understand your point...